# Can't find prop in vuetify.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use the vuetify.js component `v-select`, https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects,  in my app, dark mode. The problem is, I can't find a prop to change the background color of the dropdown drawer from the default brown color.

The only relevant prop I found, `background-color`, changes the background of the selection box, not the drawer.

I tried manually changing the background color also, but the navigation drawer is built off of so many individual components (each with the background color) that I couldn't find a way to do it. Am I missing a prop/way to do this?

Comment: In my opinion you can redefine some variable in the stylus for this, I do not remember exactly which change. https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/stylus/settings/_theme.styl

Comment: uses [vuetify theme](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme) or something like `.v-list {
  background-color: red !important;
}` (not recommanded)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using a very hacky way [here](https://codepen.io/amitkh/pen/bOPBJe). Basically, you will set `background-color` of each item in the list to the color of your choice and then remove `padding` and `height` properties from `.v-list` globally (this is because vuetify puts all the dialogs and dropdown lists at the global level in your app)